# How to set user login credentials to Spark webUI in apache spark open source cluser

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-plugins

We are using open source apache spark cluster in our project. Need some help on following ones.

1. How to enable login credentials for spark web ui login?
2. How to disable “kill button” option from spark webui?.

Can someone help me solutions to question 1 or 2 or both?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sure. According to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html) you need to set `spark.ui.filters` setting to refer to the filter class that implements the authentication method you want to deploy. Spark does not provide any built-in authentication filters.
   You can see a filter example [here](https://gist.github.com/neolitec/8953607).
2. You need to modify ACLs to control who has access to modify a running Spark application. It can be done by configuring parameters `spark.acls.enable`, `spark.ui.view.acls` and `spark.ui.view.acls.groups`. You can read more about it [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#spark-history-server-acls).